# Función para eliminar valores de una columna de datos en un archivo csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dispongo de un csv file que es más o menos así:

```
ID,A,B,C
1,1,1,Y
2,1,2,Y/N
3,1,2,Y/N
4,2,3,N
```

Estoy intentando eliminar del csv file las filas que contienen Y/N en la columna C.

No entiendo qué falla en el siguiente código:

```
import csv
with open('file_2.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as inp, open('file_3.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                             quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in csv.DictReader(inp, dialect='unix', delimiter=","):
        if row[3] != "Y/N":
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Traducido.py", line 13, in <module>
    if row[3] != "Y/N":
KeyError: 3
```

Alternativamente, me serviría también sustituir los Y/N por N, si esto fuera más fácil.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` retorna un diccionario por cada fila, en concreto un objeto `collections.OrderectDict`.

No puedes usar indexación en un diccionario, debes usar la clave, que en este caso es el nombre de la columna ("C"):

```
if row["C"] != "Y/N":
```

Por otro lado, para poder escribir las líneas en forma de diccionario debes usar la clase `csv.DictWriter` en vez de `csv.writer`:

```
import csv

with open('Libro.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as inp, open('file_3.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, dialect='unix', delimiter=",", quotechar='"',
                            fieldnames =("ID","A","B","C") , quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(inp, dialect='unix', delimiter=","):
        if row["C"] != "Y/N":
            writer.writerow(row)
```

La línea `writer.writeheader()` se encarga de escribir la primera línea que son las cabeceras de cada columna. Si no las deseas solo tienes que eliminarla.

El atributo `fieldnames` debe recibir una secuencia con los nombres de las columnas a escribir en el orden correcto, puedes pasárselo manualmente como se hace aquí o podrías obtenerlo del archivo de origen. Es un parámetro obligatorio.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla, aprendo un montón con la ayuda vuestra. Es extraño, porque ahora, haciendo esto, obtengo en todas las filas "ID,A,B,C"

Comment: Tienes razón, es porque estas usando `csv.writer` en vez de `csv.DictWriter`. Voy a editar.

Comment: Vaya parece que ahora tengo otro, TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fieldnames'

Comment: Si ya he editado, ese parámetro debe ser un iterable con los nombres de las columnas a escribir. Mira a ver la respuesta, estoy desde un móvil y no descarto algún error tipográfico o cosas similares... Aunque creo que todo está bien.

Comment: Qué fenómeno eres... Está bien, me daba un error en mi código particular, pero era debido al orden específico de mis columnas. El código funciona. Muchas gracias de veras.